# Using guava AbstractScheduledService

Tags: java, guava

I'm trying to execute some task periodically using guava [AbstractScheduledService](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractScheduledService.html) :

```
public class MyService extends AbstractScheduledService {

    public MyService() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void runOneIteration() {
        doStuff();
    }

    private void doStuff() {
    // Do stuff
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Scheduler scheduler() {
        return Scheduler.newFixedRateSchedule(0, 8, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    }

}
```

So this service should execute some task periodically every 8 hours but it never actually does. The inherited `isRunning()` method returns false and the `runOneIteration()` method never gets invoked.

I have managed to make it work by calling the `startAsync()` method (inherited from parent class) from my service constructor but I don't see any reference saying this is the way it should work.

Have I missed something here? Is this the way the `AbstractScheduledService` works?

Comment: Note, that next execution will scheduled ONLY after runOneIteration returns.

Comment: Not sure I'm getting you. If I don't call the startAsync() method the service never runs.

Comment: Aren't you better with Quartz for your implementation? It looks like you want a Quartz' Task to be run, not a Guava's Service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AbstractScheduledServiced` implements [Service](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Service.html). The Service interface describes lifecycle methods including `startAsync`. The [ServiceState](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Service.State.html#RUNNING) enum literals contain documentation on what they mean. A Service in `NEW` state (just created):

> A service in this state is inactive. It does minimal work and consumes minimal resources.

For the Service to do something useful you have to transition it to the state `RUNNING`

> A service in this state is operational.

That's why you have to start the Service before it does anything.

I would also advise against calling startAsync from the constructor and instead calling it from the Code that creates your `MyService` instance. It is rarely an expected thing to have such heavy side effects (creation of Threads) in the constructor.

Comment: I'm using IOC by Spring so the service is created by Spring container. Since the service should be in use immediately once my application server starts I rather start it from the constructor. Regarding your answer - I still try to understand if calling startAsync() is the recommended practice for using AbstractScheduledServiced

Comment: As the AbstractScheduledServiced is a Service and needs to be started. Yes you should call startAsync on it.

Comment: You use it with Spring, then inject all your Services in a bean and in a @PostConstruct method (or the Spring equivalent), start them all. Don't start your service in your constructor.

Comment: The typical practice for `Service`s (when you're using multiple services anyway) is to inject them all into a `ServiceManager` and then start up the `ServiceManager` to start all the services. You can then shut down the `ServiceManager` when shutting down your application to shut down all the services, and the `ServiceManager` additionally provides the ability to check that all of the application's services are healthy.